# Syntax for defining 'pool' in KNEX/BookshelfJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js, heroku-postgres

Firstly, I'm new to everything here... and new to StackOverflow, so apologies in advance for being a newbie and I'm ready for my thrashing... LOL.

We use a Heroku.addon for Postgres and utilize/reference environment variables globally to access the right database.

We have a config.js file in our application's root directory like:

```
  db: process.env.DB_URL || {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      database: 'db_name',
      user: 'user_name'
    }
  },
```

Would someone here be able to guide me on how to integrate code that initializes 'custom pool' information into this setup like the example found on 
[http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling][http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling]

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }
});
```

On Heroku, process.env.DB_URL is a complex URL that is similar to:

```
postgres://(redacted)@ec5-87-1-47-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d8n2e9ebd0q9it
```

So, I am hoping there is a clean way to also pass 'custom pool' information as well either here or in another file/location.

The database is referenced throughout the backend of our application via Bookshelf/Knex.  The reference to bookshelf looks similar to:

```
var knex = require('knex')(config.db);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it by reading just connection details from env variable, like this:

```
db: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DB_URL || {
      database: 'db_name',
      user: 'user_name'
    },
    pool: { min:5, max:20 }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael.  This is very helpful!